# Why are most types in C# inherited from System.Object?

Tags: c#, java, .net, performance, object

I was checking the int and float types in C# and even they have the "ToString" etc, methods meaning they are inherited from System.Object. But Doesn't this cause a performance hit? I understand that they did not make base types like int objects in java because of performance. Doesn't this rule apply to .NET as well? And if it does, then does that mean .NET is slower than Java? But practically that's not true because the programs i have made in C# run way better than those I made in Java. So is there something I don't understand here?

Comment: For more on the subject: [Type system unification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664638%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Comment: There are so many down-votes on these answers! If you *do* down-vote, please explain why so I can understand!

Comment: You have just accepted the wrong answer...

Comment: @burningprodigy: I did not vote you down :-)

Comment: @burning +1 for a good question - there is clearly confusion even amongst solid .NET developers.

Comment: @whoever_voted_me_down  if (vote.hasbeendowned()) {vote++}

Comment: @burning... Thanks for the question... I learned something... although I'm not sure it's useful, because my original view of value types and reference types remains unchanged. But Rick does have the "right" answer... although I'm not sure about his use of "appears".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's very important to understand the differences between value types and reference types. The core of the difference is what the value of an expression of the type is.

Consider:

```
int x = 10;
SomeClass y = new SomeClass();
```

Here, the value of `x` really is 10 - the bits for 10 end up in the memory associated with the variable `x`.

The value of `y` is a *reference* - a way of getting to a separate object in memory.

The difference becomes very important when you use assignment, particularly with *mutable* reference types:

```
int x1 = 10;
int x2 = x1;
SomeClass y1 = new SomeClass();
SomeClass y2 = y1;

y1.SomeProperty = "Fred";
Console.WriteLine(y2.SomeProperty);
```

In both cases, the *value* of the variable is copied in the assignment - so `x2`'s value is 10; `y2`'s value is a *reference to the same object*. So when the object's data is modified via the property in the penultimate, you can still see that difference via `y2`.

You would rarely write `z1.SomeProperty = ...` when `z1` is a variable of a value type, as most value types are *immutable*. (You can't change the value of the data itself - you have to assign a new value to the variable explicitly.) If you *did*, however you wouldn't see any changes via variables which were previously initialized using an assignment `z1` because the *value* would have been copied in that assignment.

I have an [article on value types and reference types](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html) which goes into all this in more detail.

---

Now, C# and .NET have a unified type system such that even value types *inherit* from `System.Object`. That means you can call all the messages from `Object` on value type values. *Sometimes* that requires boxing (converting a value type value into an `Object`) and sometimes it doesn't... I won't go into all the rules right now. Importantly, if a value type overrides an object method (e.g. `ToString`, or `GetHashCode`) the value *doesn't* need to be boxed to call the method.

While boxing *does* have a performance penalty, it's [typically overstated in my experience](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/10/08/why-boxing-doesn-t-keep-me-awake-at-nights.aspx). These days with generics, boxing isn't really needed as much as it used to be - but so long as you only use it sensibly, it's unlikely to become a significant performance problem in your application.

---

EDIT: Regarding games, performance, and learning things a bit at a time...

I've seen *lots* of people asking questions on a relatively advanced topic without understanding the basics. There's nothing wrong with being a beginner, obviously, but in my view it's *really* important to learn the basics first, in a "newbie friendly" environment - which I don't think games count as.

Personally I find that console apps are the easiest way of learning most core new concepts - whether that's language features, file IO, collections, web services, threading etc. Obviously for things like "learning Windows Forms" you can't do that with a console app - but it really helps if *nothing* other than the Windows Forms part is new to you.

So I would strongly advise that you learn the basics of C# - things like how value types and reference types work, how parameter passing works, generics, classes, inheritance etc - before you move onto games. That may sound like extra work, but it's likely to *save* you time later on. When something doesn't behave as you expect it to, you'll know how the *language* works, so you can focus on the *API* behaving differently, etc. Trying to learn one thing at a time makes the whole process smoother, in my experience.

In particular, the performance requirements of games mean that sometimes it's worth writing very non-idiomatic C#. Things like preallocating objects and reusing them where you'd normally create new objects... even creating mutable structs which I'd pretty much *never* do in normal development. In the critical game loop, boxing *or creating any objects at all* may be a bad idea - but that doesn't mean these things are "expensive" in the normal frame of reference. It's **really important** that you understand when these things are appropriate, and when they're not... and if you *start* with games development, you'll get an imbalanced view of these things, IMO. You'll also potentially try to micro-optimize areas where you really *don't* need to - but if you have a solid grounding in C# and .NET to start with, you'll be in a better position to get everything in perspective.

Comment: Following up with Jon's comments about performance - one tool I've found _super_ useful has been dotTrace from JetBrains. It'll tell you where you've got problems - and where you don't. Certainly helps put the focus on the parts of your application that actually need optimization.

Comment: @Steve: Yup, absolutely. There are other profilers available as well, of course, but dotTrace is the one I've probably used most. The free Microsoft profiler (http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13382) can be good for finding which methods get called a lot etc, but it's not really the power tool that dotTrace is.

Answer (score 5):

As long as all objects **appear** to be derived from `System.Object`, then for all practical purposed they **are** derived from `System.Object`.  Underneath the hood things are optimized into perfection so that an `int` is just a four-byte `int` most of the time but it's an object when it needs to be an object.  That's what **boxing** is all about.

The compiler and the run-time both work very, very hard to make sure that primitive types are not overburdened with a lot of excess baggage in size or function.  At the same time, all rules needed to meet the C# specification and the object hierarchy are ensured.  Sometimes the compiler takes shortcuts, sometimes the run-time does the work.

Comment: Awesome, meaning that They act like objects when needed but are simple types otherwise. (Looks like I underestimated Microsoft, they really know their stuff!)

Comment: This answer is not correct either. Int is NOT an Object (reference type), it's a struct (value type).

Comment: @burningprodigy: `Looks like I underestimated Microsoft, they really know their stuff!` --> lol, no kidding...

Comment: @Steve but `int` defines `int.Equals` so when it is used as int `int x = 42; x.Equals(someObj)`, it's all good. And when "boxed" it conforms to `object`, e.g. `object x = 42; x.Equals(someObj)` -- still good, by contract of `object`. Now, the details of the boxing ... I don't know :(

Comment: @burningprodigy In some cases Microsoft design shines ... in other cases, not so much. (Ever dealt with the beast-that-is-SharePoint+InfoPath...? :-/)

Comment: @pst... that's just a static "equals" operator. There is nothing special about it, and it doesn't require you subclass Object. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: @Steve But struct (System.ValueType) is ultimately derived from System.Object.

Comment: @Steve I'm arguing for statement "As long as all objects appear to be derived from System.Object, then for all practical purposed they are derived from System.Object" ;-) I never said anything about being required to be sub-classed, although I am not sure here as far as `struct` and details :-/ Also, *[int.Equals(object) is not static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de3wwa8z.aspx)* :-)

Comment: @Steve: But they **appear** to be.  That is the OP's question.  From the C# 4.0 Specification 4.1.1: _All value types implicitly inherit from the class System.ValueType, which, in turn, inherits from class object_

Comment: @pst... yes, it is, you're allowing yourself to get confused by the C# compiler. When it's compiled into MSIL it uses a static equals operator method.

Comment: @Steve Not relevant to *C# code* :-)

Comment: @pst... I understand what you're arguing for, but it's not the thrust of the OP's question, which is: "But Doesn't this cause a performance hit?"

Comment: @pst... yes, is relevant to C# code, since it's an ECMA-defined standard with a specified implementation.

Answer (score 0):

One advantage of having a common base class means that you could write a method like
public void DoSomething(Object object)
{ 
....
}

and essentially pass in anything.

Not sure about the performance aspect though.

Comment: Int and Float, as the poster refers to, are not subclasses of System.Object.

Comment: I see, but does that mean you can make derived classes out of types too? like:  "class MyInteger : int "?

Comment: @Steve then why do they have all the methods of System.Object?

Comment: @burningprodigy No. "Value Types" -- those defined with `struct` such as `int` (aka `System.Int32`) -- *cannot* be extended.

Comment: But what pisses me off is languages which abuse this feature to tack on "RepresentableAsString" and "Hashable" to the base class...

Comment: @Jeremy Really?  I find it handy.

Comment: @Steve Yeah . So they are structs NOT objects...

Comment: @recursive: No, boxing doesn't convert *into* a struct. It converts a value type value into an *object*.

Comment: @Jay Handy? Really? Wouldn't it be more handy if only the objects which provided that functionality were of that type?  Right now there's no way to specify "Really make this argument hashable!  I mean it!" because the fake hashable objects and real ones have exactly the same type hierarchy.  Oh, and I forgot to mention Cloneable, but that's a whole other level of pain.

Comment: @Jon Skeet:  I stand corrected.  I based that on the fact that VS says "struct" in the tooltip if you hover over int.

Comment: @recursive: Yes, `int` is a struct. But boxing creates an object to effectively wrap a value.

Comment: Even if structs existed in a separate "universe" from class types, one could still have "universal method" if one had a variation of a `params` declaration which would specify that the compiler should generate for each item either a new single-item array or a new instance of generic object-wrapper class, since all arrays are class objects, regardless of the element type.  Actually, it would in some cases be nice to have such a declaration wrap *everything*, so that passing a variable of type `Animal` which held an instance of `SiameseCat` would pass a `Cat[]` containing the instance.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: To clarify my position on boxing: Jon said it well when he asked me to point out: "[boxing is] as expensive as creating any other small object". So, I don't mean to overstate the performance impact. However, I do intent to arm intelligent readers with the information they need to make *smart* decisions based on their *individual circumstances*.

EDIT: OK, so if you want to be technical, I retract my previous statement. From C# ECMA standard: "All value types implicitly inherit from class object. It is not possible for any type to derive from a value type, and value types are thus implicitly sealed (§17.1.1.2)." (C# ECMA Standard Page 130) HOWEVER... It's my understanding that the thrust of the OP's question is really in relation to PERFORMANCE and how the types are treated under the hood in .NET. To that point: Value Types ARE treated differently from Reference Types - and simple types (int, float, etc) are stored and operated upon in an efficient manner. When they ARE treated like Objects, you pay an expensive performance cost (as the OP suspects). The moral of this story is, for me, and hopefully maybe someone else, is to AVOID BOXING - which, in practical terms, means Value Types ARE different from Object... take my answer as you may.

---

You are mistaken. System.Integer and System.Float are not subclasses of System.Object. They are what's referred to as "Value Types".

you can see this is true in the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx which shows that Int is a "struct".

This article discusses the topic in detail: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34yytbws%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

You should definitely read that last one if you're interested in this.

In regards to your broader question, "Why are most types in C# inherited from System.Object", you'll find there is nothing unique about this. Java has java.lang.Object, Objective-C has NSObject, etc. etc. The distinction between value types and reference types is nearly universal. I'm not sure I really need to get into the long-winded answer to that here, because I think pointing out the difference, and the article about value types in C#, has already probably answered your question.

To clarify everyone else's questions about boxing, etc.: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301569.aspx

Comment: So to follow through with this question (not entirely answered by your 2nd article) - When you call `ToString` on an `int`, does it get boxed?

Comment: ??? any type in C# is subclass of System.Object type. Consider to remove your false statement.

Comment: Thanks! Finally some enlightenment!

Comment: @gorik: Read the docs. They aren't Objects, they are value types (structs), not reference types (Object).

Comment: @Steve: isn't System.ValueType subclass of System.Object? Please see link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.valuetype.aspx

Comment: @Steve: System.ValueType is indeed a subclass of System.Object. Every class in C# is a subtype of System.Object. That's why you can do something as (object)myInt.

Comment: @Falanwe: yes, that's called boxing, and it's not the "default" state of a value type, it's a performance-crushing poor design when you treat value types that way: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx

Comment: @Everyone Do you mean that Everything in C# is derived from System.Object but types like int and float are still passed by value. But if they are derived from System.Object , aren't they objects themselves meaning they should be passed by reference?

Comment: "In relation to simple assignments, boxing and unboxing are computationally expensive processes. When a value type is boxed, a new object must be allocated and constructed. To a lesser degree, the cast required for unboxing is also expensive computationally." Microsoft -> DOes this mean that it DOES cause a performance hit?

Comment: @burningprodigy: C# doesn't use pass-by-reference by default; it passed references by value. Boxing *does* have a performance hit, but it's not terrible. It creates an object when you box, that's all. Yes, that has a hit, but it's not "performance crushing" unless you use it in a daft way.

Comment: More on boxing performance, btw: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2008/10/08/why-boxing-doesn-t-keep-me-awake-at-nights.aspx

Comment: "Boxing and unboxing are computationally expensive processes. When a value type is boxed, an entirely new object must be created. This can take up to 20 times longer than an assignment. When unboxing, the casting process can take four times as long as an assignment" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173196%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: @Steve: Yes, it's more expensive than a simple assignment (one of the cheapest things you can do). That's not the same as saying it's "performance crushing". Compared with pretty much *any* IO, it's incredibly cheap. When used sensibly, boxing isn't "performance-crushing" at all - the way you've described it, one would expect that any application using boxing at all will run as slow as molasses, and that's simply not true.

Comment: @Jon, understood... and I have great respect for you, so I'm hesitant to disagree with you at all... but the OP's original question was asking about performance, and I'd say that - if treating a value type like an Object results in an (up to) 20x performance hit - that there is a functional difference and his suspicion about performance is warranted. He said nothing about the types of applications he's developing. Maybe SETI FFT algos for all we know.

Comment: @Steve: And in that case, you wouldn't want to use boxing all over the place, sure. It's true that there *is* a cost - but you've vastly overstated it, telling people to avoid boxing without explaining anything about the *relative* performance costs. The way you've written it, if I were a newbie reading the answer, I'd assume that boxing should never occur in my code, and that it's a sure sign of a killer performance problem if it it does. That's simply not the case.

Comment: @gorik no, there are C# types that aren't derived from `object` - pointers (`unsafe`) etc.

Comment: @Steve - I have to agree with @Jon here; in most cases (especially on regular .NET with a generational garbage collector) boxing is *not* a problem. It gets more complex on things like CF/XNA, though

Comment: @Jon, with the exception of the question title, and the first and last sentences of the post, everything he asked revolved around performance. If he retitled the post: "Performance impact of the unified type system in .NET" (which is my interpretation of his question), my guess is the answers would be vastly different, and my assessment of the performance hit would be viewed as accurate. I have some doubts about the accuracy of that sample app, and I'd be interested if you did a deep-dive into the MSIL (and ultimately the x86 when NGENed) generated by your different test cases.

Comment: @Jon, I did +1 your answer though, because we clearly have no real disagreement here - more a difference of opinion regarding the focus of the question I think.

Comment: Well , My Question was strongly related to performance. Since I am currently writing games in C# instead of C/C++ like I used to.

Comment: @Steve: Sure, the question is somewhat around performance - although I think it reveals a deeper lack of understanding, which is more important to clear up. We've established that most of the time, boxing doesn't occur, and that's fine... but we appear to disagree significantly about whether the performance cost of boxing is just "something to bear in mind" - like the cost of virtual method invocation, reflection, exceptions etc, or something which will kill your performance dead. In other words, it's micro-optimization.

Comment: @burningprodigy: If you're writing a XNA game you *would* want to avoid boxing if possible - but to be honest, writing games in C# is likely to require larger changes to style anyway. You'll want to avoid *any* memory allocation in the main game loop if you can, mostly to avoid garbage collection in a performance-critical path. But the good news is that .NET *won't* be treating your value type values as objects unless you end up boxing them. It's important to know that you *can* still call methods like GetHashCode() without boxing, so long as they're overridden in the value type.

Comment: I see. So as long as I don't use any methods i'm safe. Thanks!

Comment: @Jon, No, I don't think we even disagree about that. I simply biased my answer towards what I believed the bias of the question was (which was confirmed by the author who said "strongly related to performance" not "somewhat around performance". I mostly write standard business-type apps and would never think about boxing performance day-to-day -- but when someone's asking about performance or talking about the CLR -- I think it's fair to answer their question within that context, and put down the banner of code-readability that we all carry with us most of the time.

Comment: @Steve: How does that fit with: "The moral of this story is, for me, and hopefully maybe someone else, is to AVOID BOXING"? Bear in mind that many people who ask about performance do so when they shouldn't be thinking about performance yet at all. As it happens, within the main loop of a game, boxing *would* generally be a bad idea - as would creating any other object. But that doesn't mean it's good advice to give in general, or that it would be accurate to describe object creation as "performance-crushing". Boxing is still not nearly as expensive as the impression you give.

Comment: @burningprodigy: "So as long as I don't use any methods i'm safe" - that's not what I said at all. You won't get very far in .NET without using methods. As it sounds like you're really a beginner when it comes to C#, I would personally recommend *against* starting off with games development - at least action, performance-sensitive development. You need a firmer base on which to start. At the moment you're hopping around from one micro-optimization to another, without understanding the basics of the platform. That's not a good idea.

Comment: @Jon, I guess I assume people are smart and will take advice given in a particular context as just that. To me, when a minor change results in a 20x performance hit (and, the OP did say he's working on a game - and you do agree with me that he should avoid boxing if possible) - my comments seem warranted in this situation - both IMO, and by your own admission. I certainly would not perform an operation similar to boxing on the iphone in objective-c for no reason. No one would. It'd just be crazy. You've setup a strawman argument that if I'm pro-performance awareness I must be anti-readability.

Comment: @burning, @jon: WHOA... "As it sounds like you're really a beginner when it comes to C#, I would personally recommend against starting off with games development - at least action, performance-sensitive development." burning: I don't interpret your question that way at all - I think you asked a good question - and I think it was just that - a question. We all learn by doing - make all the games you want, and learn a lot - just like the rest of us. There is no "right path" to .NET development. If you want to use .NET to make games - then go for it. You'll learn about what you care about.

Comment: @Steve: I've never claimed you're anti-readability. I'm claiming you're *vastly* exaggerating the performance cost of boxing. It's about the same as creating another small object - not free, but really not that expensive. You should avoid boxing to the same extent as you avoid creating other objects - if it makes the code simpler to create an extra object you don't *strictly* need, then in many cases that's still the right thing to do. Note that we only found out that games were involved *after* you'd made most of your performance comments.

Comment: @Steve: As for the business about whether it's a good idea to try to dive into the deep end - that needs a rather longer answer. I'll edit my answer to explain what I mean.

Comment: @Steve: Answer edited appropriately now.

Comment: @Steve: I think we'll have to agree to disagree. I've seen the performance impact of boxing overstated (with no frame of reference) time and time again - even by smart people like Jeff Richter. Yes, boxing can cause a performance problem if it's *hugely overused* - but it's not nearly as expensive as you've made it out to be. You think I'm elitist, I think you're being a scare-monger. If I were new to C# and read your post and comments, I'd be left with the impression that any code using boxing was a performance death-trap. The truth is *much* gentler.

Comment: @Steve: In particular, just changing your post to say that boxing is "as expensive as creating any other small object" would at least give readers a frame of reference. Would you tell people to "AVOID CREATING OBJECTS" in the same way?  Would you call creating an object an "expensive performance cost"? That's all boxing is - creating (small) objects implicitly. I guess we'd better not start discussing the performance impact of exceptions ;)

Comment: @Jon, "Would you call creating an object an "expensive performance cost"?" - in many cases where performance is a concern, yes. (Games, graphically-intense applications, memory-constrained scenarios like mobile development, scientific/mathematical computations, etc.) Any time you need to allocate room in memory you pay a cost - in terms of memory fragmentation, memory pressure, cpu cycles, OS interrupt time, etc. In the case of .NET it's even worse because you're adding one more thing for the GC to reclaim - which can cause strange pauses in your app, etc. *Post edited with your sugg. change.

Comment: @Steve: Thanks for the edit. In the context of a game, these *can* be significant, but frankly there are all kinds of things which games do which I wouldn't normally consider, as discussed further in my answer. I think it's worth being *very* clear that boxing, when used sensibly, is only likely to be a significant performance hit in very specialized circumstances... and most of the time, devs should really check that they're *in* those circumstances before assuming it. (See http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/16/just-how-spiky-is-your-traffic.aspx for an example.)